# Cloning from forked or cloning from main repository?

Tags: git, github

Is cloning from main repository and cloning from forked repository different?
I forked a repository but cloned it from the main repository. Now when I am trying to push my local code to remote, it returns a error saying that access is denied. What did I do wrong?

Comment: The difference is that in one case the remote is the main repository and in the other case the remote is the forked repository.

Comment: Did you want to push your changes to the main or the forked repository?

Comment: To the forked repo

Comment: Then you need to set up the forked repository as a remote.